# Regex that doesn't end with a specific character compilation issue

Tags: regex

I have to make a regex that covers this conditions:

- The word can start with non mandatory _
- Followed by [a-zA-Z]
- Followed by [a-zA-Z0-9_] -- 0 or more times
- And it cannot end with _

I have implemented this solution:

```
_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^_]$
```

This regex can detect variables like:

try_it

But it cannot detect variables like:

x, y, z

This regex will be used for lexical analysis

**Acceptable**:

```
a100__version_2
_a100__version2
x
y
z
```

**Non acceptable**:

```
100__version_2
a100__version2_
_100__version_2
a100--version-2
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` requires there to be a letter; `[^_]` requires there to be a second character.

Comment: `[^_]` matches *any* non-underscore, such as `$`

Answer (score 2):

If a negative lookbehind is supported:

```
^_?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$(?<!_)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `_?` Match an optional underscore
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed chars
- `$` End of string
- `(?<!_)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `_` directly to the left

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gIgemF/1).

Or matching word characters and 0 or more leading underscores using `_*` as in the pattern in the question:

```
^_*[a-zA-Z]\w*$(?<!_)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PiIASc/1).

Comment: negative look behind is not a standard regex

Comment: @Andrew There is no such thing as a "standard regex" that is why the answer starts with `If a negative lookbehind is supported:` It depends on the tool or language and the regex flavour.

Comment: I standby my assertion that negative look behind is non-standard. it is not part of POSIX (basic or extended), nor part of regex as taught at accredited universities in the USA in a formal language theory CS class.

Comment: @Andrew You can stand by your assertion, that is all good. You can see an overview of regex engines and features here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines and see that there are quite a few that support the lookbehind assertion.

Comment: @bokaj92  Per the regex tag description, "Specify the language (PHP, Python, etc) or tool (grep, VS Code, Google Analytics, etc) that you are using. "--that would help prevent this current debate.  :-)

Comment: So, i am using it for a compiler in flex & bison. Using this regex, i get errors for bad characters. I think that this is from ?<

Answer (score 1):

This one may come in handy for matching your accepted words:

```
^_?[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[^_])?$
```

Regex Explanation:

- `^`: start of string symbol
- `_?`: an optional underscore
- `[a-zA-Z]`: a letter
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[^_])?`: an optional set of characters that doesn't end with an underscore
- `$`: end of string symbol

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fnatDp/1).

Optional Note: If you're allowing only alphanumerical character for the last non-underscore, you can change `[^_]` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: this will accept ~ as the last char, which is wrong

Comment: This regex follows OP's rules, including allowing `~` as the last char.

Comment: No it does not. It says "*And* it cannot end with _".  It does NOT say "followed by any char that is not _ as the last char"

Answer (score 0):

^_\?  ==>  can start with non mandatory _

[a-zA-Z]  ==>  followed by [a-zA-Z] (also satisfies next 2 criterion, hence the \? below)

\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$  ==> followed by [a-zA-Z0-9_] -- 0 or more times and it cannot end with _

...putting it all together and testing is shown below:

```
Mac_3.2.57$echo "a100__version_2" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
a100__version_2
Mac_3.2.57$echo "_a100__version2" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
_a100__version2
Mac_3.2.57$echo "x" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
x
Mac_3.2.57$echo "y" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
y
Mac_3.2.57$echo "z" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
z
Mac_3.2.57$echo "100__version_2" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
Mac_3.2.57$echo "a100__version2_" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
Mac_3.2.57$echo "_100__version_2" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
Mac_3.2.57$echo "a100--version-2" | grep '^_\?[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\)\?$'
```